# error while trying to serve a Dingo-protected download from Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, download

I am using Laravel 4 & dingo 0.8.3 trying to serve a dynamically created export file as a download in response to a protected route and am getting an error from inside dingo

I know that L4 is out of date, but this project was started over a year ago and is < 2 months away from delivery

Is there any workaround that I can use to get this done?

The file contains dynamically created json

(in routes.php)

```
Route::group([ 'protected' => true ], function(){
    Route::resource('bundle', 'Bundle');
    Route::get('bundle/download/{id}', 'Bundle@download');
```

(in Bundle.php)

```
$contents = $this->createBookletExport($id);
$nameForFile = $contents->exportName .'.intbnd';
$pathToFile = "/tmp/".$nameForFile;
File::put( $pathToFile, json_encode($contents) );
return Response::download($pathToFile,$nameForFile);
```

(in laravel.log)

```
[2016-02-21 13:57:24] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::getFormatter()' in [...]/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php:220
```

(from dingo/composer.json)

```
"require-dev": {
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.4.*",
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "0.8-dev"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this -- the answer was NOT to use the Response::download but to use Response::make and add some headers (I had tried headers with Response::download to no avail)

So this:

```
$contents = $this->createBookletExport($id);
$nameForFile = $contents->exportName .'.intbnd';
$pathToFile = "/tmp/".$nameForFile;
File::put( $pathToFile, json_encode($contents) );
return Response::download($pathToFile,$nameForFile);
```

Became this:

```
$contents = $this->createBookletExport($id);
$nameForFile = $contents->exportName .'.intbnd';
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream', 'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='.$nameForFile);
return Response::make(json_encode($contents),200,$headers);
```

and Dingo! Bob's yer Uncle !!

:)